# Javascript/Jquery Event Listener for Input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, javascript-objects, jquery-events

What I want to happen is that after the member is selected, the province, town, and barangay will be automatically input but I want to add another listener for the province to do another query for shipping method but my code is not working in:

```
$("#member_id").change(function () {
    var value=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type : 'get',
        url : '/panel/admin/members/search_id',
        data:{'search':value},
        success:function(data){
            //console.log(data);
            $("#loading_member").css("display", "block");
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#loading_member").css("display", "none");
                $('#province').val(data.province);
                $('#city_town').val(data.city_num);
                $('#brgy').val(data.brgy);
                $('#member_code').val(data.member_code);
            },500);
        } 
    });
});


const provincelist = document.querySelector('#province');

provincelist.addEventListener('provincelist', updateValue);

function updateValue() {
    var value=$('#province').val();
    $.ajax({
        type : 'get',
        url : '{{route("panel.admin.search_province")}}',
        data:{'search':value},
        success:function(data){
            $("#loading_shipping").css("display", "block");
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#loading_shipping").css("display", "none");
                $('#shipping_method').find('option').remove().end();
                $('#shipping_method').append(data);
            },500);
        } 
    });
    console.log(value);
}
```

Somebody help me?

Comment: What is happening with your code now? Are you getting any errors? What part of your expectation is not happening? Share more information including errors you are getting and html code

Comment: *"is not working"* tells us nothing of value such as what it is expected to do, what exactly isn't working and what it should do differently and errors encountered (if any)

Comment: @AlwaysaLearner const provincelist = document.querySelector('#province');

provincelist.addEventListener('provincelist', updateValue);

this listener is not working.. I do not know if that is the correct way to handle onchange or on keyup when the #province input has a value

Comment: if you like `updateValue` to be called when province is changed, why not call it directly from inside ajax success after value of 'province' is updated? You are attaching an eventListener named 'provincelist' to field 'province', but this is never triggered.

Comment: @AlwaysaLearner that is what I did when I realized.. hehehe. Thank you.